# How can I get emacs to see ZSH's environment variables when I open it from /Applications

Tags: terminal, zsh, emacs

When I launch emacs from ZSH, it works as desired.  Specifically, it sees that my HOME directory is `/Users/myname/Dropbox`, so it looks for `.emacs.d` there.

Unfortunately, when double-click the emacs icon in my Applications folder (/Applications/Emacs), this behavior is not present.  Launching with Alfred gives the same behavior as double-clicking the icon.

Is there any way I can make the GUI-launch more closely mimic the command-line launch?

I guess another way to ask this question is -- from what environment is the application launching when I double-click the icon or launch with Alfred?